# Added gmail with custom domain to outlook.com as 'connected account', can send emails as gmail account but not receive emails

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-imap, outlook.com

As the title says, I can now send emails as the gmail email I added however the outlook.com account does not receive emails sent to the gmail account, even though it imports the gmail emails at the start of the connection, creating the same folder structure as the gmail account and adding the emails that are already in the inbox.

Answer (score -2):

You have to configure your POP/IMAP settings ( as per your requirements ) in the outlook account settings and enable the same settings in GMail settings.

Here's a link on how to configure outlook account :

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404274/how-can-i-set-up-email-in-outlook

Here's another link on how to change POP/IMAP settings ( as what you've selected in outlook ) in GMail :

http://coderoman.com/2013/01/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-gmail/

Go to GMail>settings>POP/IMAP>Enable POP/IMAP.

Comment: The question is about Outlook.com but your answer is about Office Outlook. The former is a website; the latter is an app.

Comment: Additionally, you failed to quote and cite the relevant information from your links, anyone can submit an answer with relevant links.